Uniqueness of solution to central path for linear program
Given the primal LP $\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} c^Tx \text{ s.t. } Ax \leq b$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b\in \mathbb{R}^m,c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ one can derive the dual LP $\sup_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}^m}-b^T\mu \text{ s.t. } A^T\mu = -c, \mu \geq 0$.
We assume the following constraint qualification conditions:

There exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax < b$.
There exists $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\mu > 0$ and $A^T\mu = -c$.
The rows of $A$, denoted $a^i, i = 1,\dots,m$ are linearly independent.

Then given $\varepsilon > 0$ it is straightforward to derive the central path system:
\begin{align*}
A^T\mu &= -c\\
\mu_i(b_i - (a^i)^Tx) &= \varepsilon,~~ i=1,\dots, m\\
Ax &\leq b\\
\mu &\geq 0\\
\mu \in \mathbb{R}^m&, x\in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}
I understand in this situation that the solution $(x,\mu)$ is unique. Is the uniqueness of $\mu$ obvious purely from the condition $A^T\mu = -c$, and can $\mu$ be solved for independently of $x$?
Maybe I should write my uncertainty: if $A$ has linearly independent rows, then $A^T\mu = -c$ has at most one solution. In this case we know it has a solution as assumed in condition 2. So this must be it. But then there isn't really any work to do, which is confusing me.

This is the Fundamental Lemma of Interior Point Methods for LP. The central path system is the KKT system of the log-barrier minimization of LP, which has strictly convex objective. Thus, $x(\mu)$ is unique. To argue the $\mu$ is unique, as you pointed out, this can be directly seen from condition 3, which is LICQ (guarantee unique dual solution).
